# Setting a Style to a Static Resource for a root Control element

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to set the style of the root `Control` element in my XAML to a `StaticResource` defined in an external `ResourceDictionary`, however I receive the error:

`The resource "MyControlStyle" could not be resolved.`

```
<UserControl
    ...
    >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Styles\MyStyles.xaml" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.Style>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyControlStyle"/>
   </UserControl.Style>

</UserControl>
```

Aside from setting the style in the the XAML file that makes use of my control, how can this be accomplished?  I'd like to be able to set the style from within the `UserControl` so that I can see the effects of the style in the designer for the `UserControl`.

Comment: Are you using an App.xaml in your project with your MergedDictionaries declaration pointing to your resource dictionaries to make them available to the project you're working in? You shouldn't need to declare your Resource Dictionary path in your UserControl to inherit the style templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make a reference to a ResourceDictionary that is defined inside the control from an user control's property (Style in this case). The resources work as a bubble, if a control need a resources, then it search in its container's resources, if not find there, then search in the parent of the container's resurces, if not find it search in its parent....
until the application resources, and if not found in the system resources.

If you want to apply a resource to  the user control, then you should put it inside the application resources (in the App.xaml file). Try this.